# A term for multiples made by using an odd/even factor

Tags: terminology, integers

(I bet you will send me to [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com) and they will send me back here)

I will use an example - I have two lists of integers:

- list A: 0, 4, 8, 12, ...
- list B: 2, 6, 10, 14, ...

I'm looking for a neat word to clearly differentiate these lists when talking to a colleague who doesn't really have a maths mindset. My intuition is:

- list A is "even multiples of 2"
- list B is "odd multiples of 2"

I tried to google this sort of wording, but I get mixed results:

- Some results use these words the way I came up with, which is promising;
- Some results would only call *n* and odd multiple of *k* if *n* itself is an odd number (and thus *k* is odd too);
- Some results also use the word "odd" as another word for "unusual" (which is odd, haha)

So what is the term for multiples made by using an odd/even factor?

Hopefully by now you can see why I struggled to come up with a good title for this question.

EDIT: A comment from GerryMyerson hints that I probably used an unfortunate *k* in my example. I'm after a word that will work for any *k*, whether or odd or even (although "pateksan's odd multiples" of odd *k* are actually odd numbers). So for example list A might be 0, 8, 16, 24, ... and list B might be 4, 12, 20, 28, ...

Comment: The first set is $4\mathbb{Z}$ and the next one is $4 \mathbb{Z}+2.$ Or replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{N}_0$ if you only want non-negative integers.

Comment: I'm looking for a neat _word_

Comment: Perhaps "non negative numbers that are multiples of four" and "non negative numbers that leave a remainder of two on division by four"?

Comment: How about: "Arithmetic Progression" ?

Comment: $A$ is *doubly even* numbers, $B$ is *singly even* numbers. Sez https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singly_and_doubly_even

Comment: @GerryMyerson If I saw that terminology without knowing what that meant, I'm not sure I'd guess what you/wikipedia intend it to mean.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it's a start, but I need a word that will work for any _k_, not just _k_ = 2 so I added that as an edit to my question.

Comment: @Don I won't disagree with you, but OP asked "what is the term...?" and insofar as there is a term this seems to be it.

Comment: If that's what you want, pateksan, then that's what you should ask for. We're mathematicians here, not mindreaders.

Comment: It's not *wrong* to use "even multiples of $2$" and "odd multiples of $2$". After all, it's not uncommon for someone to write, say, that $\sin\theta=0$ (or $\cos\theta=0$) when $\theta$ is "an even (or odd) multiple of $90^\circ$". That said, as you indicate, "even" and "odd" can be read/heard as referring to the *resulting number*, not the *multiplier*, which is problematic. You *could* coin terms like "doubled-even numbers" vs "doubled-odd numbers". Or you could just go with "even/odd multiples of $2$", pausing after the first usage to clearly define what you mean by the term.

Comment: I don't think there is a common (one- or two-word) term for what you want, and the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences doesn't give one. You could try "$k$-times-even" and "$k$-times-odd", or "even-times-$k$" and "odd-times-$k$".

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  what is wrong with modulo?  The original examples are $0 \pmod 4$ and $2 \pmod 4$.  I think that does what OP wants.  I would have suggested that

Comment: @Blue You might be onto something. A quick search of this website for "multiple of pi" gives lots of examples of "my" usage. So it would seem it's become acceptable for irrational _k_ because no multiples of such will ever be odd or even, therefore no risk of misunderstanding whether the word odd/even applies to _factor_ or _result_.

Comment: @Ross sure, that'll do. Will pateksan be happy with it? More generally, $0\bmod{2k}$ and $k\bmod{2k}$.

Comment: @pateksan: One also sees "rational multiples of $\pi$", as in the classic "When does a rational multiple of $\pi$ have a rational (co)sine?" Be that as it may ... If I were forced to suggest a way to convey that the adjective (even/odd/rational) applies to the *factor*, not the *result*, I might advocate for hyphenation: eg, "even-multiples of $2$", "odd-multiples of $2$", "rational-multiples of $\pi$". ... That said, if you're seeking a robust descriptive construction that works w/ any set of multipliers applied to any multiply-ee, you might actually need *notation* instead of *terminology*.

Comment: Any thoughts on the suggestion of @Ross, pateksan?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for following up. Briefly, for now I would lean towards the two comments from Blue (Jul 24 at 2:54 and Jul 24 at 3:56). But I will continue mulling over this and may come back here one day.

Answer (score 1):

We use the term modulo to describe what is left when you divide integers by a number $m$.  Your example of $0,4,8,12,\ldots$ are the numbers equivalent to $0$ modulo $4$, often written $n \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  The numbers $2,6,10,14,\ldots$ are equivalent to $2 \pmod 4$.  Does that do what you want?